# add html list from behind code?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a database that I need to turn into a list for a webpage. I have the data bound to a gridview in the page_load function of a behind code file. I was wondering how I could take my grid data and create a ul/li list with it. Here's my function so far:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Service1 myService = new Service1();

        //Use a gridview to store the table data before building the menu
        GridView sites = new GridView();

        sites.DataSource = myService.GetAllSites();
        sites.DataBind();



        foreach (GridViewRow siteRow in sites.Rows)
        {

            String itemName = siteRow.Cells[1].Text;              

        }
```

Also, does anyone know how to make a list expandable? So that clicking one list item will cause a div or something to open right below it, moving the list items down a bit to make room?

Answer (score 0):

What you've described sounds very close to the asp.net `TreeView` control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2(v=vs.80).aspx

Adding to the tree:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(site.Name));
```

A pretty easy to follow example here:

http://www.nullskull.com/q/10328363/treeview-in-aspnet-with-examples.aspx